# Issue with SQLiteDatabase.query() when SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery() works fine

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am having issue querying my SQLITE database in Android.  I have a table called "resets" with some values in them.  Currently I only have one entry.

```
reset_timestamp | interval
1479442048      | 5
```

This is the query I was trying to execute.  However, it returns zero results when I call cursor.getCount().  The query I want to execute is:

```
SELECT reset_timestamp FROM resets WHERE (reset_timestamp=1479442048);
```

I don't really want to use rawQuery().  I want to use query().  Here is my query statement.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = new PowerDbHelper(this).getWritableDatabase();
String[] resetsQueryColumns = {"reset_timestamp"};
String[] resetsQuerySelectArgs = {"1479442048"};

Cursor cursor = db.query("resets", resetsQueryColumns, "reset_timestamp=?",
                resetsQuerySelectArgs, null, null, null);
```

However, getCount() returns 0 with this.  On the other hand, this works fine and returns my result

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("select reset_timestamp from resets where (reset_timestamp=1479442048)", null);
```

and getCount() returns 1, what I want.  Putting quotes around '?' gives me

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range
```

What am I doing wrong with query()?

Comment: And when I refer to getCount(), I'm refering to cursor.getCount().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"1479442048"` is a string (you even wrote `String` in front of it). A string and a number are not equal.

The `query` function supports only string parameters, so you have to convert the string back into a number:

```
query(..., "reset_timestamp=CAST(? AS INT)", ...);
```

Alternatively, insert the number directly into the query:

```
query(..., "reset_timestamp=1479442048", null, ...);
```